# How to fit larger layout to a small device screen?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, meta

I've got a little issue with `meta viewport` element. The problem is that my layout `min-width` is larger than lots of screen resolutions I want to work with. So setting it like

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

does not help. As result i get the page, that has to be zoomed out to fit to the device width. And if i even add scales like

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=1" />
```

it does not work either. 
Found a hack from [Css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/fix-ie-10-on-windows-phone-8-viewport/) that did not help too.
So the final question is : how to fit larger layout to a smaller screen?
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.
Oh, forgot to say, testing it on Lumia 525, Iphone 4, Ipad 2.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I can not specify the width, cause I've got liquid layout, with just min-width. The larger gets screen, the larger gets the page.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 min-width on `body` is specified. And u r talking about smth like `float:left;` on body? 
Am i correct?

Comment: Oh, I just reread your question. Are you trying to scale down the page to make it "fit" on a smaller screen? (I thought you were trying to achieve something else)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Yep, I'm trying to scale it out on load to fit the screen.

Comment: I tested on Chrome on Android, and by default pages that exceeds the width of the viewport are automatically zoomed out. I'm not sure about iPhone though. I also found this code `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=0.25">` which worths a try.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Thank you for your effort, but it did not help. I think my WP ignores viewport tag completely.

Answer (score 0):

set `Zoom` to `0.00000001`.
The more the value is scaled lower, the more zoom out you'll get.

```
content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.00000001".
```